# How to store multipe queryset results in a list, then display values in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Id like to store a filtered queryset in a list and then iterate over the list in my template.

I have a list of tenants in my model stored like so:

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contract_end = models.DateField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

View like so:

```
def expiry(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    tenant_queryset = Tenant.objects.all()
    expired_list = []

    for x in range(0, 12):
        date = now + relativedelta(months=x)
        expired = tenant_queryset.filter(
            contract_end__year=date.year,
            contract_end__month=date.month
            )
        expired_list.append(expired)

context = {"expired_list": expired_list}

return render(request, "expired_template.html", context)
```

Template:

```
{% for tenant in expired_list %}
{{ tenant.first_name }}<br>
{{ tenant.telephone }}<br>
{{ tenant.contract_end }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Im using a for loop in my view to go through the months of the year, then storing those results in a list.

I cant seem to get tenant.first_name, tenant.last_name, tenant.telephone and tenant.contract_end values to display in my template. Im guessing this is because Im already outputting the results of my filtered queryset to a list and its displaying those results rather than a 'reference', if that makes sense.

How can I go about this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the below answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted, please. It's a good practice in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are appending each time in your `expired_list` a `QuerySet`.

Change `append` to this:

```
expired_list += expired
```

So that, you finally get a unified (flatten) `QuerySet` (list).

Python (very simple) example:

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = [1, 2, 3]
list_1.append(list_2)
print(list_1)  # [[1, 2, 3]]

list_1 = []
list_2 = [1, 2, 3]
list_1 += list_2
print(list_1)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I got it working! Thank you for your help. Think Im going to have to do some reading on the differences between append, += and i = i + 1 in python. Im trying to group all my results now by each month. Ive come up with a solution where I could create a list for each month and populate each list but seems a little long winded.

Comment: Glad I could help. Mark answer as correct please, so this question has been resolved!

Comment: In this case, you should ask a new question so others (and you, in the future) can search more efficiently!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!!